# How to compare and get object value in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS object ( data will be diffrent , it's just for example  )

```
{10: 0, 
    30: 2.5, 
    365: 15, 
    730: 25, 
    1095: 35}
```

Key is Days and value is percentage.
Now
if input is between 0 to 10 days then percentage will be 0,
if between 11 to 30 days then percentage will be 2.5
if between 31 to 365 days then percentage will be 15
if 1100 days then 35

here is my code

```
days - > input 
obj_data - object 
    jQuery.each(obj_data, function(key, val) {
        if( days <= key ){
            console.log(val);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true
```

here how to get value if days are greater than to 1095

Comment: You should use `if(days>1095){/*Your code here*/}`

Comment: 1095 is not static. days and percentage will from object. so days can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a value that is higher than anything else for what's possible, you have a value you can check for.
If that value is returned, get the "largest"/"last" value from the provided values.

In the example below I use concat to add the largest safe integer to the array, so the compare function keeps running.

If that value is returned, we know we didn't have a match, so we get the last value from the provided object.

```js
let data = {10: 0, 
    30: 2.5, 
    365: 15, 
    730: 25, 
    1095: 35}
let days = [1,11,31,366,731,1096]
function find(day, obj) 
{
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  result = keys.concat(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).filter(key => {
     return day <= key;
  }).shift();
  
  if(result === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
     result = keys.pop();
  }
  return obj[result];
}
days.forEach(day => console.log(day, " gets value:",find(day, data)))
```

Comment: Thanks. its working.  Now i am trying with MAX_SAFE_INTEGER to get  lowest value. if between 10 to 29 days then percentage will be 0 (not 2.5 ). but i am getting result same as above code.  Thanks